# PHP Undefined offset explode time

Tags: php

This code works, but I get a message error:

> Undefined offset

When a using this code:

```
$total = strftime("%H:%M",$h3);
$total2 = strftime("%H:%M",$h6);

$a = explode(':',$total);
$t1 = $a[0]*3600+$a[1]*60+$a[2]; / /<-- this line error code

$a = explode(':',$total2);
$t2 = $a[0]*3600+$a[1]*60+$a[2];  //<-- this line error code

$t3 = $t1 + $t2;

$h = floor($t3/3600);
$m = floor(($t3%3600)/60);
$s = $t3-$h*3600-$m*60;

$sumtime = $h.':'.$m.':'.$s;
```

Comment: Do `print_r($total);` <- And you will see that it only has 2 indexes, so you try to access an undefined offset of the array!

Comment: $a = explode(':','01:10:02'); 
$t1 = $a[0]*3600+$a[1]*60+$a[2]; / /<-- this line error code

$a = explode(':','08:05:00);
$t2 = $a[0]*3600+$a[1]*60+$a[2];  //<-- this line error code

$t3 = $t1 + $t2;

$h = floor($t3/3600);
$m = floor(($t3%3600)/60);
$s = $t3-$h*3600-$m*60;

$sumtime = $h.':'.$m.':'.$s;

Answer (score 0):

`%H:%M` tells that there will be only two elements separated by `:`. If you use explode on that you will receive array with two elements therefore when you use `$a[2]` you get an error. Simply index 2 does not exist. Your array's max index is 1.

From what I see you try also add seconds which you do not use in strftime

Comment: with this same problem   $a = explode(':','08:00:00');

Answer (score -1):

i found solution thank you

$a1=explode(':',$total);

$t1=$a1[0]*3600+$a1[1]*60;

$a2=explode(':',$total2);

$t2=$a2[0]*3600+$a2[1]*60;

$t3=$t1+$t2;

$h=floor($t3/3600);

$m=floor(($t3%3600)/60);

//$s=$t3-$h*3600-$m*60;

$sumtime = $h.':'.$m ;

Comment: Just wanted to say I gave the down-vote for the reason that what you have added for this answer, is what @Rizier123 had commented for you in the firs place. there was no need for this answer. you could just edit your question and update it and add your new code(solution) to it.